# First character of the input text is always read by TextWatcher even when I've cleared my textfield completely

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textwatcher

What I am trying to do is, to call another activity with the help of intent, if and only if my edittext field `name` is not empty.

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, contacts.class);
        name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                String text=name.getText().toString().trim();
                if(!text.isEmpty()) {
                    //println(s.toString());
                    Log.d("name",text.toString());
                    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

                            if (checkedId != -1) {
                                if (rb.getText() == "custom") {
                                    intent.putExtra("FLAG", flag);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                } else {
                                    flag = false;
                                    intent.putExtra("FLAG", flag);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    //println(s.toString());
                    Log.d("name",text.toString());
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Please type your name", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.show();
                }


            }
        });
```

When I run the code, after typing in something in my edittext field (`name`) and then deleting it completely, still allows the intent to call the new activity, which puzzles me.

So, I started debugging this with the help of `Logcat`and found out that the first character of the input that I give is never actually deleted and is readable by TextWatcher.

For example: Suppose I write **Hello** in my textfield, then my Logcat is like

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
```

This is fine. But, the problem arises when I start clearing the text. The characters get deleted like:

```
Hell
Hel
He
H
```

Even when my edittext field is completely empty, that first character of the string (`H`) is still read by TextWatcher. Why?

Comment: Try to write code inside  after text changed listener

Comment: Wrote it inside `afterTextChanged()` too, still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the code to fire your intent is when you click one of the two RadioButton , so when you actually write something , you had just set a listener to that radio buttons , and let me tell you this , you edit text is actually empty and the logcat show you the last letter to exist in the EditText field which is H , after H it was empty so there are nothing to be printed in the logcat !

You will get my point if you try to click the radio button without touching the EditText , it will not fire the intent , but if you write even a one letter , then the radio click listener will registered and ready to fire the intent !

Now I will tell you what you have to do , first EditText listener :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, contacts.class);
```

And then set radio button click :

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText.toString())){
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
                      if (checkedId != -1) {
                           if (rb.getText() == "custom") {
                              intent.putExtra("FLAG", flag);
                              startActivity(intent);
                           } else {
                              flag = false;
                              intent.putExtra("FLAG", flag);
                              startActivity(intent);
                          }
                      }
            }
       }
});
```

**Enjoy !**